# Variable Scope Question for Ruby Newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am going through the book 'Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial' and came across the part where I have to write some basic unit tests for my static pages. I noticed the code replicated with just some text changes, so I change it to be the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']

  before(:each) do
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
  end

  pages.each do |page|
    describe "GET '#{page}'" do
      it "should be successful" do
        get "#{page}"
        response.should be_success
      end

      it "should have the right title" do
        get "#{page}"
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => @base_title + page.capitalize)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

What I am confused about in the above example is that I can replace the 'pages' variable with this:

```
@pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
```

And it still works. Why is that? How are '@pages' and 'pages' different?

The other confusing thing is that both of these cause the tests to fail:

```
pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
@base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
```

And

```
before(:each) do
  pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
  @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
end
```

Why do the above 2 examples fail? Why must the code look like what I posted in my first code snippet? I presume this has something to do with variable scope, but I am still new to Ruby so I am looking for deeper understanding.

FWIW, I am an experienced C# developer, so getting comparable Java or C# code would help me understand this or a well written description.

Thanks for any support.

Edit:
Added error message from when I move the @base_title outside of the 'before' block.

```
Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => @base_title + page.capitalize)
NoMethodError:
   You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
   You might have expected an instance of Array.
   The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
 # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: For the 1st snippet, what is the method it's in ? Please post that context. Also, if you use `@pages` (i.e. an instance variable, not a local variable `pages`) in the 3rd snippet, does it work?

Comment: I added the rest of the method.

Comment: What is the failed test details?

Comment: I added the error message I am getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

K, I am going to answer your questions in order...

**1.** When you make the change from

```
pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
```

to...

```
@pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
```

You are merely changing a local variable into an instance variable... this should not work, and should cause your tests to break...

**2.** The following code shouldn't work.

```
pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
@base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
```

This is because @base_title will not be available to your 'it "" do' blocks. The variable pages will be in scope... but you have the @base_title error condition.

**3.** This won't work either.

```
before(:each) do
  pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']
  @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "
end
```

The variable pages being defined here is out of scope for the each loop you have. @base_title will be fine, and will carry onto all your methods perfectly.

**- Conclusion -**

The final sample you posted is correct. You merely needed a local variable for the each loop, and an instance variable (@base_title) so that it is available to the entire instantiated class while the tests run. Hopefully this is some help to you. I would suggest looking at a few other ruby tutorials online, personally I like sending people to http://rubykoans.com/ =)

One last note, RSpec is a complicated case for scoping since it uses a lot of blocks and moves code around quite a bit to do what it needs to. Basically you have blocks inside of blocks... things can quickly get tricky. I would start with some simpler examples.

Comment: This is probably the closest solution. The reason #1 works in both cases is due to the scope at which I am accessing the @pages variable.

Comment: I can also do `pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help']` and `base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | "` outside of the before block and it works. It appears in that case, the `base_title` variable gets scoped at the PagesController level.

Comment: Here is a really good read on why my cases were failing: [Variable Scoping](http://ruby.runpaint.org/variables)

Comment: I was confused, I thought you meant that @pages = ['home', 'contact', 'about', 'help'] then pages.each do |page| was what you had... which should not work. Not replacing the var in both the top level and the each with @pages

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I was changing all instances of `pages` to `@pages`. Looking at your answer and the link I provided, I was able to review my code to understand my scoping question.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby you create an accessor method to allow external code to access instance variables:

```
class Foo
  def pages
    @pages
  end

  def pages=(value)
    @pages = value
  end
end
```

If you're accessing `@pages` from within the class, it's going to be the same thing as accessing `pages` from within the class, which will call `self.pages`, returning `@pages`.